# How information is collected from a photographic sensor

Tags: wire, transfer-function, data

For example, you have a sensor measuring temperature, light intensity or anything else.

You have microcontroller reading your data and a sd card to save your data.
I can understand how you can collected data from 1(one) point. But the plate is a mass of points.

Pixel separation happens after transfer, doesn't it?
How can I transfer all of this information on a wire ?
Where can I read about this part of electronics?...

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the datasheet for [CMOS image sensors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cmos+image+sensor+datasheet&t=opera&ia=images), this will give you a good idea how a sensor array (a "plate") can send large amounts of data. Short answer: very quickly, one (or a small group) at a time.

Comment: It used to be done by firing an electron beam at the sensor, and collecting the charge released on another electrode. You could steer the e-beam, so you steered it to each part of the sensor in turn to get a serial stream of analog voltages. Then, pixel separation was a matter of looking at the stream at the right time. Now, sensors are already a 2D array of pixels; you just need to address them correctly. (Sometimes you address a line and see a stream of pixels)

Comment: The same way you eat an elephant, one byte (or bit) at a time. Serially. But usually a bunch of processing takes place between reading the bitmap image from the CMOS sensor (sometimes CCD sensor) and saving a .jpg file to the SD card. Read about Bayer filters and image compression.

Comment: Serial data can be sent down a wire in an audio sequence, like a fax machine.

Comment: brave new world..ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensors like CCDs used in cameras split the photograph into pixels so the pixels are produced before data transfer.

The pixels are transferred from the CCD as a serial data stream with the CCD acting as a shift register. Sometimes more than one data stream can be read at a time.

For more information Google CCD.